# I think he will need vs I think he needs

Tags: meaning-in-context

Please describe the right sentence or both are appropriates? Is it right that the first one is more about future, may be in a month. But the second sentence is more about now, already need.

> He is a little tired – I think he **will need** a good holiday.

vs

> He is a little tired – I think he **needs** a good holiday.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct for the reasons you state. The first implies a need soon while the second implies a need now. However, if you're looking for advice on American English, change holiday to vacation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *will need* obviously refers to the future.

"By the time he has finished that exhausting job he will need a holiday."

It could also refer to something required for a journey or task that a person is about to start.

"Are you cooking dinner? You will need to put on an apron."