# what you need to know later

Tags: tense, usage

**Boy**: You don't pay me to work for you.

**Woman**: No, because what you do here in the workshop isn't a real job.

**Boy**: It isn't a real job?

**Woman**: No. I'm training you for a real job later.

**Boy**: You're training me?

**Woman**: Yes, I'm training you or teaching you **what you need to know later**.

---

Which is correct:

1-what **you** need to know later.

2- what **you'll** need to know later.

Thank you

Comment: They are both fine. The form with _will_ sounds slightly more natural to me but that may just be a matter of style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["I will start my course ..." Or "I start my course ..."](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119639/i-will-start-my-course-or-i-start-my-course) Also [“he leaves for New York tomorrow”. vs. “he will leave for New York tomorrow”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/88972/) and [I think he will need vs I think he needs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/243625/i-think-he-will-need-vs-i-think-he-needs) and probably several others.

Comment: The dialog is rather "forced".  Why would the boy not be aware that he wasn't being paid?  Anyway, welcome back rezaellstack. I see you are still using this odd resource to learn English.  This is your regular reminder that there are much better learning resources available.